# Where is Visual Studio reading the web.config file from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-config

I have a web project which compiles a few DLL's.  There are 4 Projects in this solution and 3 of them generate DLLs

**AT DEVELOPMENT TIME**

I'm trying to read some settings from the Web.config file. However I'm getting null values.

If the Call to read the setting from the web.config is in one of the Projects that generates a DLL, should the Web.config be in the project for that DLL?

**AT RUN TIME ON SERVER**

The DLLs are in a sub directory (\bin| under the page.aspx
Would the DLL be reading values from the \bin dir it's in, or the dir the page.aspx (which calls the dll) ?

Comment: Your web project has web.config and you can place the settings in that web.config file and can read those settings inside your class library projects. Since your web project has references to the class library projects or the dlls generated from these projects, at runtime the configuration settings will be loaded from web.config file

Comment: "I'm trying to read some settings from the Web.config file. However I'm getting null values." How? Any code?